# How to plot a 2D ellipse (with its interior color filled) in 3D?

Tags: python, plot, 3d, ellipse

I've seen [how to plot a color filled ellipse in 2D](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.html). I would like to plot ellipses like that, but in a 3D plot.

Comment: Do you want a 2d ellipse in 3d, or a 3d ellipsoid?

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to use PyPlot. Now, PyPlot makes MatPlotLib work like MATLAB. Now, in order to make an ellipse you can try the below example code.

```
from pylab import figure, show, rand
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

NUM = 100 

ells = [Ellipse(xy=rand(2)*10, width=rand(), height=rand(), angle=rand()*360)
        for i in range(NUM)]

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
for e in ells:
    ax.add_artist(e)
    e.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
    e.set_alpha(rand())
    e.set_facecolor(rand(3))

ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)

show()
```